# PayFast "Pay Now" Button for Wordpress Blog

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I have a very interesting scenario, well, for me at least. I'm trying to add a PayFast "Pay Now" button to a Wordpress.com blog. Specifically in one of the sidebar text widgets. Now the challenge is that the customer must put the amount in manually.

I've done this with PayPal, easy, but PayFast is a bit more challenging for me. I've trolled the internet and the closest I came was:
 [Adding Own amount on payment button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22780771/adding-own-amount-on-payment-button).
Which actually helped a lot as it made me realize that Wordpress.com blog site text widgets doesn't seem to like JavaScript for some reason.

So.... This is the code I'm currently working with:

```
href="https://www.payfast.co.za/eng/process?cmd=_paynow&receiver=jmwvermeulen%40gmail.com&item_name=Donations&amount=50.00"
```

(edited so that it displays in the post)

First question: `amount=50.00` needs to be a variable. The customer needs to be able to put an amount in which he/she wants to put in.

Second question: Can one create this purely in HTML, as the widgets don't like the JavaScript "function" and "variables"

I hope this is sort of clear.
Any input and suggestions are greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In order to generate the HTML button code follow these steps:

1. Log into your PayFast account
2. On your Dashboard under Pay Now Buttons click on ‘generate’
3. You will be taken to a form titled Enter Button Information, fill in the necessary fields
4. Click on ‘create button’ and the HTML code will appear, this can be used in an email or on your website

For more details you can see details on below link:

https://www.payfast.co.za/html-buttons/

Comment: Hi Mohammed, Thank you for the feedback. I tried this previously, because that also gives one the option for the customer to enter his own amount. It just seems that the Text/HTML Wordpress Blog Widget doesn't like javascript. I wish I could show you a picture of what it does. it reads the <script language and type> section fine, but actually displays all the code from the "function" all the way down to just before </script>. Hope this makes sense

Comment: @WesselVermeulen, the following plugin will allow you to paste JavaScript into the text editor for WordPress https://wordpress.org/plugins/dont-muck-my-markup/ .